# Overloading as.logical in base R

Tags: r

I want to simplify some little text generating code. Default arguments to program are 0 length character when that function is not to be used. I'm interested in something simpler than

`if (nchar(expr) > 0) ...`

So I created the following

```
as.logical <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("as.logical")
as.logical.default <- function (x, ...)  base::as.logical(x, ...)
as.logical.character <- function (x, ...) nchar(x) > 0
```

If I try some examples in the command line, it works

```
> as.logical(letters)
 [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE ...
```

But interestingly, the `cond` "logical" vector doesn't attempt to apply `as.logical`. It seems to be used in other cases as below:

```
> if (1) print('Has')
[1] "Has"
> if ('Has') print(1)
Error in if ("Has") print(1) : argument is not interpretable as logical
```

How does `cond` evaluate and can't I fool it into using my function?

Comment: Your function definition is masking the usual primitive version of `as.logical` but it doesn't seem to be recognized by `if`. You would need to look at the source code of `if` to see what is happening underneath the hood. I suspect the answer to the last question is a flat out NO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source, the base R `if` statement doesn't do implicit coercion to logical in 
a generic way. Here's [the code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/bf4cf8912596162a3ae5a2b7da1a74220105b172/src/main/eval.c#L2107). It does call `asLogical` in the C code on the expression, but that version of `asLogical` doesn't do generic dispatching (since the default `as.logical` isn't generic). If a character string is passed in, it will only run [LogicalFromString](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/3a1693cabd68ae8a8003ff2b74d0ba20b51a092e/src/main/coerce.c#L1770) which only recognizes a [hard-coded limited number of strings as TRUE](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/e1fdc8473d9dae7f012b02c07600f699a585438f/src/main/util.c#L117): "T", "True", "TRUE", "true". There's no way to change that behavior in the user space unless you wanted to write some sort of "if" function type thing (you can't really write your own statements).

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think to check `if`. Is it possible to rewrite `if` in base R?

Comment: You can't create your own statements. You'd have to write some sort of functional wrapper, maybe similar to the way `ifelse` looks.

Answer (score 1):

Echoing Mr. Flick's answer that a wrapper is needed. This is just such a wrapper that seems to solve the problem:

```
newif <- function(cond, expr) {
  answer <- as.logical(eval(cond))
  if (answer) {
    invisible(eval(expr))
  }
}

> newif('Has', print(1))
[1] 1
```